# Check to see if last friday is in the same week PHP

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to create a PHP script that displays information depending on the day from Monday to Sunday however on the last Friday of every month the data needs to be different from normal Fridays

**Example PHP:**

```
<?php
$today = date('w');
$mtime=1;
$ttime=2;   
$wtime=3;
$thtime=4;
$ftime=5;
$stime=6;
$sutime=0;

echo "<div>";
if($mtime == $today) { echo $monday_fetch; }
if($ttime == $today) { echo $tuesday_fetch; }
if($wtime == $today) { echo $wednesday_fetch; }
if($thtime == $today) { echo $thursday_fetch; }
if($ftime == $today) { echo $friday_fetch; }
if($stime == $today) { echo $saturday_fetch; }
if($sutime == $today) { echo $sunday_fetch; }
echo "</div>";
?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Monday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tuesday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wednesday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thursday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Friday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Saturday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sunday</a></li>
</ul>
```

However I need help when it comes to the last Friday in the month during current week e.g.

```
if("...last friday in month in current week...") { 
    echo $last_friday_fetch; 
} else { 
    echo $friday_fetch 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function for this.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
    $last_friday = strtotime('last Friday of this month');
    // ...

    // when you're checking if it's the last friday
    if (date("Y-m-d") == date("Y-m-d", $last_friday)) {
        echo "Last friday!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise you could do that with strtotime

Comment: I've just tried this out using the second and third week of the month and it doesn't seem to be working